# how to validate numbers and special characters only with regex in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have function to validate user input a against numbers-special chars pattern (no alpha)but i have not do it exactly,and i searched over the internet to find such this but i not find,any help

```
function  validate_num($input){

    return ( ! preg_match("^[0-9*#+]+$", $input)) ? FALSE : TRUE;


}
```

Comment: You forgot the regex delimiters - `"/^[0-9*#+]+$/"`. But it is not clear what format you need to support, please add valid and invalid sample inputs

Comment: thanks man you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your RegEx is not right. You need to add `/` before and after:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9*#+]+$/", $input))
```

Your RegEx seems right:

[image: pre]

The example from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) looks like this:

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```